# Hermite functions: Global maxima form decreasing sequence?

Tags: functions, orthogonal-polynomials, hermite-polynomials

Let
\begin{equation}
\psi_n(x) = \left(\frac{1}{\pi} \right)^{\frac{1}{4}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n n!}} H_n(x) e^{- \frac{x^2}{2}} 
\end{equation}
be the n-th Hermite function, where $H_n(x)$ denotes the "n-th physicists' Hermite polynomial". If one considers the plots of $\psi_n$ for different values of $n$ (cp. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#/media/File:Herm50.svg ) it looks like, that the sequence $(\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |\psi_n(x)|)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is decreasing. Unfortunately I was not able to find any result in this direction. Do you know some results regarding this sequence?

Answer (score 1):

This is proven in the following [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2034406?casa_token=Shm1TxuqcG0AAAAA:V8W7p4vy1DFsV8ILzlvRpmm0C4jT4Mrs7J9UhA9Iz32p0T3TQkz2PsDpCUfqErMMRX0PeK_c7yhmqALBK3QvjNYQFch6cgkH_tMiRhwBR9b2jGIGHr56&seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents)

An Inequality for Hermite Polynomials, Jack Indritz